# generation of a list of pairs from another list

Tags: list-manipulation

How do we create a list pair from the below list

```
list1={11,12,13,14,15,16};
```

desired pair list

```
listpair={{11,11},{11,12},{11,13},...,{11,16},{12,12},{12,13},...,{12,16},{13,13},{13,14},...,{13,16},...,{16,16}}
```

Comment: Have you seen `Subsets[]` or `Tuples[]`?

Comment: I have seen `Tuples` although I could not use it I suspected my choice. Once again I will try.

Comment: `Tuples` generates some unwanted terms such as `{12,11}`.

Comment: `Subsets` does not generate `{12,12}` or `{13,13}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select[Tuples[list1, 2], #[[1]] <= #[[2]] &];
```

How about this?